# How mathematical operations are stored in variables in c?

Tags: c

I've been using Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective to know more about computer architecture. Today, I was studying unsigned and signed addition and the handling of overflows in both cases.

I didn't have a problem with unsigned addition, so signed addition wasn't a problem because it was basically unsigned addition with conversions from signed to unsigned and unsigned to signed, also stated in the book as:

> The w-bit two’s-complement sum of two numbers has the exact same
> bit-level representation as the unsigned sum. In fact, most computers
> use the same machine instruction to perform either unsigned or signed
> addition.

Also with the formula, where w represents the word size:

[image]

Coming from this I get to the exercises and there was this exercise with a buggy code that I need to analyze

```
int tadd_ok(int x, int y) {
    int sum = x+y;
    return (sum-x == y) && (sum-y == x);
}
```

In the answer, it says the operation `sum-x` in the `sum-x == y` causes an abelian group to form so it turns into an `x+y-x` and y will be left no matter the sum value is, therefore, resulting to an incorrect evaluation.

So, here's the thing I wonder: I always thought, intuitively, that the value will be assigned after an operation to the variable, not the operation itself because if this weren't the case, the variable `sum` would just have the value of `x+y`, not the operation. Then it would result in something like `some_value-x` in the latter operation not causing an abelian group to form, so it would behave as expected. Instead, it carried the operation itself to the `sum-x == y`

Is this happening just because the value `x+y` cannot be stored in an int because of the size, so it just carries the operation, or does it always work like this, even when there's no potential overflow? If so, is it always the case for every other programming language?

Comment: `is it always the case for every other programming language` is impossible to answer. There are endless other languages.

Comment: Assignment to a variable in C does not ever store "an operation".  The assignment stores the result of the operation, including any under- or overflow that occurs.  The point of the exercise is that if x+y over/under-flows what can be stored in the `int sum`, then `sum-x` will not equal `y` as you would expect if no over/under-flow occurs.

Comment: The variable `sum` does just get the result of the addition.  The operation is not saved in `sum`.  But if sum holds the value of `x + y`, and you then subtract `x` from it, the result would be the value of `y` unless an overflow or underflow messes things up.  On most modern 2's complement machines overflow and underflow will probably wrap around such that it will work that way even then, but I don't think it's guaranteed by the standard (and I don't want to check right now).

Comment: @Outrageous Bacon, @Dmitri `The point of the exercise is that if x+y over/under-flows what can be stored in the int sum, then sum-x will not equal y as you would expect if no over/under-flow occurs.` This is the supposed behaviour, but it doesn't happen in here because of the forming of an abelian group, you can try the code it will always return 1, even if there's any overflow. That is the bug itself. If the variable itself only stores the value, it doesn't make sense for the program to create an abelian group where `sum-x == y` occurs.

Comment: Also, this is the explanation made by the book: `Two’s complement addition forms an abelian group, and so the expression (x+y)-x 
will evaluate to y regardless of whether or not the addition overflows, and that
(x+y)-y will always evaluate to x` So, basically it means: Existence of overflow or underflow will not affect the result, which is 1. If only the value is stored in `sum`, how can such thing occur? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: If overflow and underflow wrap around, then when `x + y` exceeds what an `int` can hold you get an overflow, and a predictable but incorrect result.  When you subtract `x` again, though, it will underflow and reverse the previous overflow and still give you the value of `y`, just as it would have if there'd been no overflow in the first place.  This only works if overflows and underflows wrap around appropriately, as they often do on two's complement machines.

Comment: @Dmitri Ok, this is interesting. Can you explain the `overflow and underflow wrap around` with an example, please? It wasn't mentioned in the book.

Comment: Using 8-bit numbers as examples, 1111 1111 + 1 is 0000 0000.  If you subtract 1 from 0000 0000 you should get 1111 1111 again.

Comment: 3-bit 2's complement could hold a value from -4 to +3.  If you had 3 and 2 for x and y, x + y would overflow, but would 'wrap' to -3.  Then when you subtract 3 again, it would underflow and wrap the other way, back to 2, which is what y was as expected.

Comment: @Dmitri. Thanks for the examples, now I understand it. For the record, I actually tried this with 4-bit values before asking, but, as I understand now, I miscalculated it, my bad.

Comment: lots of languages doesn't wrap the result around. For example in VB an overflow throws an exception. Some other languages like python use infinite precision so overflow never happens

Comment: If I remember, C only guarantees wrapping for unsigned integer types, but not for signed ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this:

```
int tadd_ok(int x, int y) {
    int sum = x+y;
    return (sum-x == y) && (sum-y == x);
}
```

What you'd expect is that for some values of `x` and `y` the addition will cause an overflow. For signed numbers, C does not assume anything about how signed numbers are represented (e.g. an implementation might use "twos complement" and might not) and signed integer overflows are undefined behavior (might wrap around, might format your hard drive). Because overflow is undefined behavior the compiler can do anything it likes, including assuming that it never happens (which is something that some compilers are known to do).

If the compiler does assume that the undefined behavior never happens (that `x+y` never overflows), then the compiler can also assume that `(sum-x == y) && (sum-y == x)` is always true, and the compiler can optimize the code into:

```
int tadd_ok(int x, int y) {
    return true;
}
```

> In the answer, it says the operation sum-x in the sum-x == y causes an abelian group to form so it turns into an x+y-x and y will be left no matter the sum value is, therefore, resulting to an incorrect evaluation.

That is "potentially possible in practice" (if the implementation uses "twos compliment" representation for signed integers, and if "undefined behavior" becomes wrapping/truncation) but it's not guaranteed, even if the underlying CPU uses "twos compliment" and wrapping/truncation.

> So, here's the thing I wonder: I always thought, intuitively, that the value will be assigned after an operation to the variable, not the operation itself because if this weren't the case, the variable sum would just have the value of x+y, not the operation. Then it would result in something like some_value-x in the latter operation not causing an abelian group to form, so it would behave as expected. Instead, it carried the operation itself to the sum-x == y

For "potentially possible in practice (but not guaranteed)"; the value is assigned. For example, with 16-bit `int`, with something like `tadd_ok(30000, 30000)` the `sum = x + y;` would do `sum = 30000 + 30000 = +60000 = too big to fit = -5536 due to wrapping` and then `sum - x = -5536 - 30000 = -35536 = too big to fit = +30000 due to wrapping = y`.

> Is this happening just because the value x+y cannot be stored in an int because of the size, so it just carries the operation, or does it always work like this, even when there's no potential overflow?

If it happens like this; then it happens because the first overflow (in `sum = x + y;`) causes wrapping, followed by a second overflow (in `sum - x`) and a third overflow (in `sum - y`) which cause more wrapping that cancels out the wrapping caused by the first overflow.

> If so, is it always the case for every other programming language?

It's not always the case for C. For example, with 16-bit `int` using "sign and magnitude" representation for signed integers, with something like `tadd_ok(30000, 30000)` the `sum = x + y;` could do `sum = 30000 + 30000 = +60000 = too big to fit = +27232 due to wrapping of the magnitude part only` and then `sum - x = 27232 - 30000 = -2768 != y`. Of course in this case (because it's undefined behaviour) the compiler could still always return true (as described at the start); and the same code might behave one way (with optimizer disabled) and another way (with optimizer enabled).

In general; "twos complement" is much more common and (for performance reasons) most languages don't do anything for overflows; so (without optimization) the "potentially possible in practice (but not guaranteed)" behavior isn't uncommon in other languages.